DxTrade API - How to close a position?
I am writing Python code to execute trades via the DxTrade API, via requests. At this point I can do 90% of what I need to: get prices, list open orders and positions, open orders (with stoploss). What I cannot do is close a position. And I can't find anything in the documentation that covers that.
I assume I use the "accounts/{account code}/orders" endpoint as if I were opening or modifying an existing order. But what should I specify for:
orderCode: a new unique orderCode or the orderId of the order I want to close?
positionCode: the same question
type: MARKET or STOP
positionEffect: seems like it should be CLOSE, but I have also tried opening an "opposite" MARKET order to close the existing position. Ie, same instrument and lotsize, reverse side.
I think I have tried every combination of these but nothing works. I suspect it could be a problem on my broker (Funding Traders). But it would be really helpful to learn what is the "correct" method to close a position, and then I could try it on a couple different brokers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
